# Why if I add lambda left recursion occurs?

Tags: parsing, grammar, bison, context-free-grammar, left-recursion

I am trying  to write if syntax by using flex bison and in parser I have a problem

here is a grammar for if syntax in cpp

```
    program : //start rule
         |statements;
    block:
        TOKEN_BEGIN statements ';'TOKEN_END;
    reexpression:
    |   TOKEN_OPERATOR expression;

    expression:  //x+2*a*3
        TOKEN_ID reexpression
    |   TOKEN_NUMBER reexpression;


    assignment:
        TOKEN_ID'='expression
    statement:
        assignment;
    statements:
        statement';'
    |   block
    |   if_statement;

    else_statement:
        TOKEN_ELSE statements ;

    else_if_statement:
        TOKEN_ELSE_IF '(' expression ')' statements;

    if_statement:
        TOKEN_IF '(' expression ')' statements else_if_statement else_statement;
```

I can't understand why if I replace these three rules , left recursion happen I just add lambda to These rules

```
     else_statement:
        |TOKEN_ELSE statements ;

     else_if_statement:
        |TOKEN_ELSE_IF '(' expression ')' statements;

     if_statement:
        TOKEN_IF '(' expression ')' statements else_if_statement else_statement;
```

please help me understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no *lambda* or *left-recursion* involved.

When you add *epsilon* to the if rules (making the else optional), you get conflicts, because the resulting grammar is ambiguous.  This is the classic [dangling else](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else) ambiguity where when you have TWO ifs with a single else, the else can bind to either if.

```
IF ( expr1 ) IF ( expr2 ) block1 ELSE block2
```